# How to obtain the macros defined in an Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

Is there any way, in either VBA or C# code, to get a list of the existing macros defined in a workbook?

Ideally, this list would have a method definition signatures, but just getting a list of the available macros would be great.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. This link describes several things you can do to VBA code using VBA code, including "Listing All Procedures In A Module". http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done vba for Excel in a long time, but if I remember well, the object model for the code was inaccessible through scripting.

When you try to access it, you receive the following error.

> ```
> Run-time error '1004':
> Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted
> ```

Try:

> ```
> Tools | Macro | Security |Trusted Publisher Tab
> [x] Trust access to Visual Basic Project
> ```

Now that you have access to the VB IDE, you could probably export the modules and make a text search in them, using vba / c#, using regular expressions to find sub and function declarations, then delete the exported modules.

I'm not sure if there is an other way to do this, but this should work.

You can take a look the following link, to get started with exporting the modules.
http://www.developersdex.com/vb/message.asp?p=2677&ID=%3C4FCD0AE9-5DCB-4A96-8B3C-F19C63CD3635%40microsoft.com%3E

This is where I got the information about giving thrusted access to the VB IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Martin's answer, after you trust access to the VBP, you can use this set of code to get an array of all the public subroutines in an Excel workbook's VB Project.  You can modify it to only include subs, or just funcs, or just private or just public...

```
Private Sub TryGetArrayOfDecs()
    Dim Decs() As String
    DumpProcedureDecsToArray Decs
End Sub

Public Function DumpProcedureDecsToArray(ByRef Result() As String, Optional InDoc As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim VBProj As Object
    Dim VBComp As Object
    Dim VBMod As Object

    If InDoc Is Nothing Then Set InDoc = ThisWorkbook

    ReDim Result(1 To 1500, 1 To 4)
   DumpProcedureDecsToArray = True
    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    Set VBProj = InDoc.VBProject
    Dim FuncNum As Long
    Dim FuncDec As String
    For Each VBComp In VBProj.vbcomponents
        Set VBMod = VBComp.CodeModule
        For i = 1 To VBMod.countoflines
            If IsSubroutineDeclaration(VBMod.Lines(i, 1)) Then
                FuncDec = RemoveBlanksAndDecsFromSubDec(RemoveAsVariant(VBMod.Lines(i, 1)))
                If LCase(Left(VBMod.Lines(i, 1), Len("private"))) <> "private" Then
                    FuncNum = FuncNum + 1
                    Result(FuncNum, 1) = FindToLeftOfString(InDoc.Name, ".")    '
                    Result(FuncNum, 2) = VBMod.Name
                    Result(FuncNum, 3) = GetSubName(FuncDec)
                    Result(FuncNum, 4) = VBProj.Name
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next VBComp
 PROC_END:
    Exit Function
 PROC_ERR:
    GoTo PROC_END
End Function

Private Function RemoveCharFromLeftOfString(TheString As String, RemoveChar As String) As String
    Dim Result As String
    Result = TheString
    While LCase(Left(Result, Len(RemoveChar))) = LCase(RemoveChar)
        Result = Right(Result, Len(Result) - Len(RemoveChar))
    Wend
    RemoveCharFromLeftOfString = Result
End Function

Private Function RemoveBlanksAndDecsFromSubDec(TheLine As String) As String
    Dim Result As String
    Result = TheLine
    Result = RemoveCharFromLeftOfString(Result, " ")
    Result = RemoveCharFromLeftOfString(Result, "   ")
    Result = RemoveCharFromLeftOfString(Result, "Public ")
    Result = RemoveCharFromLeftOfString(Result, "Private ")
    Result = RemoveCharFromLeftOfString(Result, " ")
    RemoveBlanksAndDecsFromSubDec = Result
End Function

Private Function RemoveAsVariant(TheLine As String) As String
    Dim Result As String
    Result = TheLine
    Result = Replace(Result, "As Variant", "")
    Result = Replace(Result, "As String", "")
    Result = Replace(Result, "Function", "")
    If InStr(1, Result, "( ") = 0 Then
        Result = Replace(Result, "(", "( ")
    End If
    RemoveAsVariant = Result
End Function

Private Function IsSubroutineDeclaration(TheLine As String) As Boolean
    If LCase(Left(RemoveBlanksAndDecsFromSubDec(TheLine), Len("Function "))) = "function " Or LCase(Left(RemoveBlanksAndDecsFromSubDec(TheLine), Len("sub "))) = "sub " Then
        IsSubroutineDeclaration = True
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetSubName(DecLine As String) As String
    GetSubName = FindToRightOfString(FindToLeftOfString(DecLine, "("), " ")
End Function

Function FindToLeftOfString(FullString As String, ToFind As String) As String
    If FullString = "" Then Exit Function
    Dim Result As String, ToFindPos As Integer
    ToFindPos = InStr(1, FullString, ToFind, vbTextCompare)
    If ToFindPos > 0 Then
        Result = Left(FullString, ToFindPos - 1)
    Else
        Result = FullString
    End If
    FindToLeftOfString = Result
End Function

Function FindToRightOfString(FullString As String, ToFind As String) As String
    If FullString = "" Then Exit Function
    Dim Result As String, ToFindPos As Integer
    ToFindPos = InStr(1, FullString, ToFind, vbTextCompare)
    Result = Right(FullString, Len(FullString) - ToFindPos + 1 - Len(ToFind))
    If ToFindPos > 0 Then
        FindToRightOfString = Result
    Else
        FindToRightOfString = FullString
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is make new sheet in book and print table with columns about all book's macro_name, link to run macro, link to open macro in ide, name of corresponding module, and sort table by module and name, if sheet is already exist and visible then it hide it, if is not then it add of make visible and print all that describe above:

```
Sub ListMacrosWithSortedLinks()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim macroName As String
    Dim moduleComp As Object
    Dim lineText As String
    Dim btn As Button
    
    ' Set the workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Add "MACROS" sheet if it doesn't exist
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("MACROS")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        ws.name = "MACROS"
    End If
    
    ' Hide "MACROS" sheet if it was visible
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Make "MACROS" sheet visible if not visible
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Or ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ws.Select ' Select the sheet
    End If
    
    ' Clear previous data and buttons in columns A, B, C, and D
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    ws.Buttons.Delete
    
    ' Write headers and make them bold
    With ws.Range("A1:D1")
        .Value = Array("Macro Name", "Run Macro", "Open VBA IDE", "Module Name")
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    
    ' Initialize row number for writing
    rowNum = 2
    
    ' Loop through all modules in the workbook
    For Each moduleComp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
        If moduleComp.Type = 1 Then ' Check if it's a module
            For i = 1 To moduleComp.codeModule.CountOfLines
                lineText = moduleComp.codeModule.Lines(i, 1)
                If InStr(1, lineText, "Sub ") = 1 Or InStr(1, lineText, "Private Sub ") = 1 Then
                    macroName = Trim(Mid(lineText, InStr(1, lineText, "Sub ") + 4))
                    macroName = Left(macroName, InStr(1, macroName, "(") - 1)
                    
                    ' Apply formatting to the cell before adding the hyperlink
                    ws.Cells(rowNum, 2).Font.color = RGB(192, 192, 192) ' Silver color
                    
                    ' Create a hyperlink-styled link to run the macro
                    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(rowNum, 2), _
                        Address:="", SubAddress:=moduleComp.name & "." & macroName, _
                        TextToDisplay:="Run Macro"
                    
                    ' Create a hyperlink to open VBA IDE
                    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(rowNum, 3), _
                        Address:="", SubAddress:=moduleComp.name & "." & macroName, _
                        TextToDisplay:="Open VBA IDE"
                    
                    ' Write macro information to worksheet
                    ws.Cells(rowNum, 1).Value = macroName
                    ws.Cells(rowNum, 4).Value = moduleComp.name
                    
                    ' Increment the row number
                    rowNum = rowNum + 1
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next moduleComp
    
    ' Sort the data by Module Name (col4) ascending, then by Macro Name (col1)
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("D2:D" & rowNum - 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("A2:A" & rowNum - 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange ws.Range("A1:D" & rowNum - 1)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub
```